# Handling Django form.save() ValueError

Tags: mysql, django, error-handling, django-forms

I am a newbie to Django error handling and I spent a week trying to figure out what exactly goes wrong when trying to update a MySQL table using Django forms. I end up with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'` error. I tried to surround the erroneous code with try catch block trapping valueError and printing the row sql query, and here's what I get.

The code:

```
def updateTask(request, task_id):
#cur_usr_sale_point = PersonUnique.objects.filter(employees__employeeuser__auth_user = request.user.id).values_list('agreementemployees__agreement_unique__sale_point_id',flat=True)
selected_task = Tasks.objects.get(id=task_id)    
responsible_people = TaskResponsiblePeople.objects.get(task_id = task_id)
task_table = Tasks. objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_form = TaskForm(request.POST,instance=selected_task)
    responsible_people_form = TaskResponsiblePeopleForm(request.POST, instance = responsible_people)
    if task_form.is_valid() and responsible_people_form.is_valid():
        responsible_people_instance = responsible_people_form.save(commit=False)
        try:
            responsible_people_instance.task = task_form.save()
            responsible_people_form.save()
        except ValueError:
            from django.db import connection
            print connection.queries[-1] 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('task_list'))
```

Print gives me an absolutely valid MySQL Select-statement (to my surpise, I expected an update-statement).

The traceback without try-catch block:

```
Internal Server Error: /task_list/update_task/200/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\djprj\task\views.py", line 101, in updateTask
    task_form.save();
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 451, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 700, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 728, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 793, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 843, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 645, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1149, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 837, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1117, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 720, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'
[10/Apr/2016 11:15:46] "POST /task_list/update_task/200/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126245
```

Help me out please !!!

EDIT: added is_valid method

Answer (score 2):

You need to first use the form's `is_valid` method:

> A Form instance has an `is_valid()` method, which runs validation routines for all its fields. When this method is called, if all fields contain valid data.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Source: [Django Docs: Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

I would recommend that you read the above documentation.

Comment: I've added is_valid method, but I still end up with the same error at the same code line.